# How to get complete SQL Text running of the query in a given SPID

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone help me please, either by giving me the query or pointing me to an article, as I can't seem to find one.

I have the SPID of a session that raised an error and we need to know the full SQL text of the query that was run by that SPID.

Can anyone help please?

Please note that I have tried the following but none of them gives me the full SQL text:

```
DECLARE @sqltext VARBINARY(128)
SELECT @sqltext = sql_handle
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = 174
SELECT TEXT
FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@sqltext)
GO

SELECT
sysprc.spid,sysprc.waittime,sysprc.lastwaittype,DB_NAME(sysprc.dbid) AS database_name,
sysprc.cpu,sysprc.physical_io,sysprc.login_time,sysprc.last_batch,sysprc.status,
sysprc.hostname,sysprc.[program_name],sysprc.cmd,sysprc.loginame,
OBJECT_NAME(sqltxt.objectid) AS [object_name],sqltxt.text
FROM sys.sysprocesses sysprc 
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sysprc.sql_handle) sqltxt
where spid = 174


DBCC INPUTBUFFER(174)
go
```

Comment: Please note that I have tried the following but none of them gives me the full SQL text:

Comment: You can get exact text only while query is running, once query completed the only way to get is through some monitoring tool. I don't think there is any readily available functionality to store SQL text upon completion of execution.

Comment: @Learning_DBAdmin, thank you for your contribution. Yes, that is the issue I'm trying to investigate i.e. can I find the complete SQL text for a query that  executed at a past point in time, and reported in error log?

Comment: Unless you've set up a mechanism to capture query metrics, as outlined in the answer by @J.D. below, you can't do this. However, you may have a chance. If the query ran for a long time or used a lot of resources, it might be in the system_health Extended Event session: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/use-the-system-health-session?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @GrantFritchey, thank you for the additional comment. I will need to do some more learning on extended events. It looks like there is no simple and ready way of getting the information I'm looking for. Thanks for your time, all the same.

Comment: You'll need to do a search inside that session. However, you can use the SSMS gui and the Live Data Explorer window to do the search. It's easier than querying the XML. Another alternative is to use DBATools which has commands for querying sessions, again, avoiding the XML.

Comment: @GrantFritchey, thanks again. I see there's even more learning for me to do  :-)

Comment: @GrantFritchey Just want to say how cool it is to find validation in something I said from someone such as yourself. Your book "SQL Server 2012 Query Performance Tuning" was my very first reference, oh some seven or so years ago, for learning about anything beyond writing basic CRUD queries in SQL Server (and specifically indexing) and is one I still keep on my desk and utilize for spreading knowledge to my colleagues. Sorry to fangirl, but what an awesome day and age we live in, to be able to cross paths. 

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I'm happy to help out any way I can.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few options available to monitor actively running queries which will provide the full query text:

1. [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15) - This is the most deprecated methodology for tracing running queries, and the tool is a bit clunky and can sometimes be difficult in searching for the exact query you're looking for if you have a lot running on your SQL instance at one time. But it is also pretty simple to use, and even provides the values of parameters used in stored procedure queries that it captures in its trace.
2. [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-ver15) - This is the recommended replacement by Microsoft to the aforementioned Profiler. While a little bit more complicated of a learning curve, Extended Events provide more in-depth information that is better searchable.
3. [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) - This is the most recent query monitoring feature released by Microsoft. Though usually intended to monitor query performance, it does provide the full text of the query as well, which can even be accessed in the [`sys.query_store_query_text` sys view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-query-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Note this feature is only available in SQL Server 2016 and later.

Each of these features need to already be running though, for you to be able to capture the query. I don't believe there's a reliable way to retroactively find the full query text, if you weren't already using a feature or tool that was monitoring what is running.

Comment: @JD, thank your for your help always. My understanding is that the above 3 methods will only give info on a currently running query. Is that correct? My issue on this occasion is to find what had been run at a past time, where the SPID is logged in error log. Do you know if that can be done?

Comment: @PTL_SQL I don't believe that can reliably be done unfortunately. Extended Events or Query Store are your best bets to setup and leave running continuously in the background (at the cost of minor performance implications - but IMO nothing to be concerned of), if you want to use a proactive solution like the above. Otherwise if you know when the query runs that you want to capture you can try to quickly run the Profiler during that timeframe instead.

Comment: @JD, thanks again. Yes, I need to get into learning extended events and Query Store. Once again, thanks for your help as always. :-)